# Уравнение в javascript

Tags: javascript

Требуется найти все возможные целые значения a, b, c, d в интервале от 21 до 70 в уравнении (a/b)*(c/d)=0.1625 при помощи javascript. Вижу это как-то так, что, как я понимаю, неверно

```
for(var a = 21; a < 70 ; a++); {
    for(var b = 21; b < 70; b++); {
        for(var c = 21; c < 70; c++); {
            for(var d = 21; d < 70; d++); {
                if (((a / b) * (c / d)) == 0.1625) {
                console.log (a; b; c; d;);
                };
            };
        };
    };            
};
```

Comment: Чтобы избежать лишних итераций циклов, стоит добавить элементарные проверки: произведение `а*с` должно быть кратным 13, а `b*d` — 80.

Answer (score 1):

Если используете перебор, то последняя переменная определяется однозначно.

То есть вы перебираете n1 вариантов переменной a, получаете n1 уравнений с переменными b, c, d, но уже без a. Аналогично поступаете с переменными b и c. У вас получится n1*n2*n3 вариантов переменной d, из которых могут попасться целые.

Сам же алгоритм можно по-разному реализовать... Решите задачу аналитически, на бумажке, а уже потом составьте программу, перебирающую целые числа.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код верен, но в синтаксисе кода ошибки. Правильно будет так:

```
for(var a = 21; a < 70 ; a++) {
    for(var b = 21; b < 70; b++) {
        for(var c = 21; c < 70; c++) {
            for(var d = 21; d < 70; d++) {
                if (((a / b) * (c / d)) == 0.1625) {
                  console.log (a, b, c, d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Исправил синтаксис, но в jsfiddle всё равно не работает

Comment: `console.log` выводит результат в консоль разработчика. В Chrome это F12 -> Вкладка "Console"

Comment: Спасибо, увидел.